# Viewstate null on postback

Tags: asp.net, listbox, postback, viewstate

So I have a listbox on my page and some textfields. Through the textfields I can add an item to my listbox (click the button, it adds it to a private List which is then set as a ViewState and the list is databound again). My listbox is also in an updatepanel which gets triggered on the button's Click event. Problem: My Viewstate remains null on a postback so it gets reset each time.

Some code:

```
private const string VIEW_INGREDIENTS = "IngredientsList";
        private const string VIEW_LANGUAGE = "CurrentLanguage";
        private List<IngredientData> _ingredientsList;

protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (ViewState[VIEW_INGREDIENTS] != null)
                {
                    _ingredientsList = (List<IngredientData>) ViewState[VIEW_INGREDIENTS];
                }

            }
            else
            {
                // prepare ingredient lists
                _ingredientsList = new List<IngredientData>();
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lstIngredients.DataSource = _ingredientsList;
            lstIngredients.DataTextField = "Text";
            lstIngredients.DataValueField = "Name";
            lstIngredients.DataBind();
        }

protected void btnAddIngredient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ingredientsList.Add(new IngredientData { Name = txtIngredientName.Text, Quantity = txtUnitQuantity.Text, Unit = lstUnits.SelectedValue });

            ViewState[VIEW_INGREDIENTS] = _ingredientsList;
            lstIngredients.DataSource = _ingredientsList;
            lstIngredients.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using vewstate during PreInit ? Try to check that a bit later during PreLoad.

Comment: That seemed to fix it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check if the page has `EnableViewState="true"`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableViewState="true" ...
```

And verify the site-wide setting in `web.config`:

```
<pages enableViewState="true" enableViewStateMac="true" ... />
```

Now ASP.NET has built-in viewstate for list controls, so I wonder why you're writing custom code for it.  The default viewstate should work well for what you're trying to accomplish.